# GROUP BY with MAX Date

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

The source table is:

```
+----------------------------+
| Col A | Col B |    Col C   |
+-------+--------------------+
|  100  |    1  |  1/2/2012  |
|  100  |    2  |  1/2/2012  |
|  100  |    3  |  1/2/2012  |
|  100  |    1  |  5/2/2012  |
|  100  |    2  |  5/2/2012  |
|  100  |    3  |  5/2/2012  |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+-----------------------------+
| Col A | Col B  |    Col C   |
+-------+--------+------------+
|  100  |    1   |   5/2/2012 |
|  100  |    2   |   5/2/2012 |
|  100  |    3   |   5/2/2012 |
+-------+--------+------------+
```

How do we obtain it using SQL?

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM Table A
GROUP BY Col C
HAVING Col C = max(Col C) AND Col A = '100'
```

But it does not seem to be working.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table A WHERE Col C = "5/2/2012" :P

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it like this?

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, MAX(ColC) ColC
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY ColA, ColB
```

Comment: You can addition add a `WHERE` to filter only specific value of `ColA` example, `WHERE ColA = '100'`

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6f5/6/0

You can use **MAX()**. Please see the fiddle above

`SELECT a, b, MAX(c)
FROM a
GROUP BY a, b`

into the consideration if this is your schema

`CREATE TABLE a(
  a INT,
  b INT,
  c DATE
);`

Comment: My suggestion is to post your query from the sql fiddle in your answer. Don't just post a link to the sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I did this quickly in ms access,

```
SELECT 
 cola, colb, max(colc)
FROM MyTbl
where cola=100
group by cola,colb
```

[image]